# Searching in files in prolog

Tags: io, prolog, instantiation-error

hello i was trying to create a code that would find a given character from an input file and print out it position, here's what i came out with "with a help from similar problems I've found"

```
process2(Text,POS):-
    open('houses.txt', read, In),
    get_char(In, Char1),
    find(Char1, In,Text,POS),
    close(In).

find(Text,In, Text, 0).
find(Char,In,Text,POS) :-
    POS is POS1 +1,
    get_char(In, Char2),
    find(Char2,In,Text,POS1).
```

however the compiler throws this error:
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Comment: The `is/2` operation requires that all variables you're computing with on the right be instantiated. In this case, `POS1` has no value, so Prolog cannot compute `POS1 + 1`.

Comment: i just moved this statement to the last and it worked:
POS is POS1 +1
thanks alot <3
any idea how to use make the function take substring instead of 1 character tho?

Comment: Before doing anything: remove the warnings you are definitely receiving!

Answer (score 2):

when handling input, always consider a DCG first:

```
:- use_module(library(pio)).

process3(File, Text, POS) :- phrase_from_file(find(Text, POS), File).

find(Text, [P|Ps]) -->
    lazy_list_character_count(P), Text, !,
    find(Text, Ps).
find(Text, Ps) --> [_], find(Text, Ps).
find(_Text, []) --> [].
```

This finds *all* positions of the input string:

```
?- process3('/home/carlo/.swiplrc', `file`, P).
P = [51, 174, 254, 452, 549, 1977, 2106, 3682, 4033|...] ;
false.
```

*edit* as suggested by Boris, the cut could remove some legitimate solution.
So here is a cut free version.

```
find(_Text, []) --> [].
find(Text, [P|Ps]) -->
    lazy_list_character_count(P), Text,
    find(Text, Ps).
find(Text, Ps) --> \+Text, [_], find(Text, Ps).
```

Comment: With [`pio`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/pio.pl) you can use also chars.

Comment: I am quite sure that the cut will prevent you from finding partially overlapping occurrences of `Text`?

Comment: @Boris: yes, you're right. Should work better without. I added it while debugging... will test and remove it. Thanks

Comment: It would be easier if you don't try to collect all positions in a list: you can always use `bagof/3` for this.

Comment: @Boris: I effectively started with your same idea. But phrase_from_file seems to require a grammar covering the *entire* file. Was exactly the problem I was debugging when I introduced the cut. phrase/3 was working with the initial version...

Comment: The solution is staring at us from the documentation of `phrase_from_file/2`: see the edit at the top of my answer!

Answer (score 1):

This works exactly as expected if you simply use CLP(FD) constraints instead of low-level arithmetic:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

find(Text, In, Text, 0).
find(Char, In, Text, POS) :-
        POS #= POS1 + 1,
        get_char(In, Char2),
        find(Char2,In,Text, POS1).
```

An advantage of the CLP(FD) version is that this is tail recursive, which is also what you intuitively did.

I also recommend `setup_call_cleanup/3`, and even better, `library(pio)` when processing files. (Note: In SICStus Prolog, you can set the Prolog flag `double_quotes` to `chars`, and then use DCGs to process a file as chars! If you are interested in this, lobby for support in SWI!)

I leave this, and fixing remaining (termination) issues in the code, as exercises.

Comment: I don't know how I feel about slapping CLPFD on top of a questionable approach. It makes it somehow both better and more questionable at the same time.

Comment: I feel exactly the same way. I have posted this only to address the prima facie question ("arguments are not sufficiently instantiated") of the OP, which has by now appeared often enough and which I want to reduce. My experience has shown me that people are unlikely to adopt too many changes at once. My hope is that even if they do not fully change to pure code immediately, they at least improve their situation *slightly*, by adopting CLP(FD). Every improvement is better than nothing.  I do include pointers to better ways though, and have upvoted the purer versions, which I highly recommend.

Comment: Why not addressing also the steadfastness-issue (in that case, without the side-effects it would be the monotonicity-issue)?

Answer (score 1):

One very clean way to do it is to use a DCG, like [the answer from CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36251091/1812457). Like him, using the nifty `library(pio)` by Ulrich Neumerkel, for example [as found in SWI-Prolog](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pio), you could combine a DCG and `phrase_from_file/2` for the following solution:

```
:- use_module(library(pio)).

... --> []|[_], ... .

file_pattern_pos(File, Pattern, Pos) :-
    phrase_from_file(( ...,
                       lazy_list_character_count(Pos),
                       Pattern,
                       ...
                     ),
                     File).
```

This is taken verbatim from the code example in the [documentation to `phrase_from_file/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=phrase_from_file/2), just added `lazy_list_character_count//1`. Unlike the other DCG answer, it generates all solutions upon backtracking. So with this file:

```
$ cat banana.txt
banana
Antananarivo
```

you get, from the top level:

```
?- file_pattern_pos("banana.txt", "ana", Pos).
Pos = 1 ;
Pos = 3 ;
Pos = 10 ;
Pos = 12 ;
false.
```

To make a list of all positions of a single character:

```
?- bagof(P, file_pattern_pos("banana.txt", "a", P), Ps).
Ps = [1, 3, 5, 10, 12, 14].
```

This solution is nice, because it is easy to get to it by just looking at the code example from the documentation to `phrase_from_file/2`. However, two problems were pointed out in the comments below:

1. An efficiency issue;
2. Using `lazy_list_character_count//1` means you cannot use this with `phrase/2`.

The efficiency issue can be solved as pointed out in the comment:

```
... --> [].
... --> [_], ... .
```

The other issue is more serious. It is maybe, after all, necessary to count the number of characters consumed. For example:

```
span(N) --> span_(0, N).

span_(N, N) --> [].
span_(N0, N) --> [_],
    {   N1 is N0 + 1
    },
    span_(N1, N).
```

Now, we can write, from the top level:

```
?- phrase_from_file(( span(Pos), "ana", ... ), "banana.txt").
Pos = 1 ;
Pos = 3 ;
Pos = 10 ;
Pos = 12 ;
false.
```

Or, using `phrase/2`:

```
?- phrase((span(P), "ana", ...), "banana").
P = 1 ;
P = 3 ;
false.
```

Comment: @repeat My solution was meant only to show how to do this with `sub_atom/5` or `sub_string/5`; however, I felt library(pio) answer was suboptimal (I gave it an s(X) anyway, with the risk of being uncool), so I added that to my answer.

Comment: @repeat dif(offensive, offending) look it up

Comment: @repeat I know exactly how the usual voting/answering crowd might react to an answer like this. I have never done it for the imaginary internet points, so I really don't care. But take a good look: the "pure" solution is on top; the solution using strings and SWI-Prolog comes with a fair warning, and suggests using `sub_atom/5` if portability is an issue. Just saying.

Comment: @repeat You are again quoting selectively. "... for the more simple cases". I stand behind this. The whole idea of strings is to allow working with _text_ (not tokens, not terms) in an efficient manner. Whether this is a good or a bad approach depends on the use case, IMHO. But you are saying that it is always a bad approach (this borders on ideology). I don't want an argument, really, so I will delete the offending, offensive comment.

Comment: @repeat PS: In the programs I have written, pure I/O as implemented in `library(pio)` in SWI-Prolog has been sometimes inadequate.

Comment: @repeat PPS Quoting selectively, leaving out important context, is one weapon of the typical demagogue. If you are not doing it on purpose then you should be more careful to avoid it. This is an advice: see the second last paragraph of [this great essay](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/columnists/chi-schmich-sunscreen-column-column.html) ("Be careful whose advice...").

Comment: Awesome answer, and comments too ! Very interesting.

Comment: Right. I had skipped the remainder of the paragraph. Diligence is the key. Will work on it!

Comment: @Boris, still: you can given more than one answer. Things will then be handled by votes. But I have to admit: I am unhappy with two of three. And the third I would not consider too appropriate, too.

Comment: `lazy_list_character_count/1` is an addition to pio that violates one of the original properties of it: that it can be used in **exactly** the same manner for files as well as for regular quoted lists be they chars or codes.

Comment: Also, `... --> []. ... --> [_], ... .` is still faster than `... --> [] | [_], ... .`

Comment: @false I see your point. I separated the two answers, and also tried to address the two issues you point out. I would very much appreciate it if you commented on the DCG + library(pio) solution. Even suggesting a better name for `skip*`....

Comment: @false I understand (which is why I asked); do you think `...//0` and `...//1` are the right choice for this?

Comment: `... //0` is a natural choice, that's what one is writing also without Prolog ... for `... //1`, not sure. `...(5)` doesn't look too nice.

Comment: @false Exactly. But since they somehow do the same, one just a bit more than the other, it would be nice if that reflected in their names. One silly idea would be to name them `.*//0` and `.//1`, but I have never liked regex notation. Or maybe `...//0` and `...^//1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are committed to using SWI-Prolog, you could use [strings](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings) for working with text in more simple cases. In this case, for example, it is enough to read a file from the stream `In` (as you have in your question) using [`read_string/3`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_string/3), and find the positions of all occurrences of a substring in it using [`sub_string/5`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_string/5):

```
setup_call_cleanup(open(File, read, In),
                   read_string(In, _, File_contents),
                   close(In)),
sub_string(File_contents, Pos, _Length, _After, Substr)
```

That's it. `Pos` will be the 0-based position of `Substr`. To find characters, just use a string of length 1. One of the best things about `sub_string/5` is that it correctly deals with partially overlapping substrings:

```
?- sub_string("banana", Pos, _, _, "ana").
Pos = 1 ;
Pos = 3 ;
false.
```

The more standard counterpart to `sub_string/5` is [`sub_atom/5`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_atom/5), with identical semantics as `sub_string/5`, but taking atoms. It should be available in every Prolog implementation.

```
?- sub_atom(banana, Pos, _, _, ana).
Pos = 1 ;
Pos = 3 ;
false.
```

After reading the whole file to codes, just use `atom_codes/2` and then `sub_atom/5`. This, however, is somewhat wasteful.

Once you have to do more complicated things with the file contents, you can move to using DCGs, [`library(pio)`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pio), etc. Going back to using reading primitives as `get_char` is usually unnecessary. However, I still would strongly recommend reading through the section of the manual on strings I linked above.

Comment: What are the overheads using: `read_atom(S, A) :- read_string(S,_,Str), atom_string(A, Str).` instead? I cannot measure the difference.

Comment: @false There is barely any difference. As you well know, the reason is that a "string" as implemented in SWI-Prolog is very space and time efficient (read "implement in C"), and the conversion from a string to an atom probably just means getting the hash of the C-string so that it can be indexed by the engine (atoms are meant to be identifiers, not holders for text). Certainly Jan Wielemaker knows more than me about the gory details. To summarize, _because_ of the implementation of strings, there is very little overhead in turning one string into an atom.

Comment: To put it differently: No reason to have strings (as a visible datatype) when atoms offer exactly that functionality.

Comment: @false I got your point :) The only argument for strings (and a very strong one IMHO) is strings as a very leaky abstraction for representing "text" make a difference once you have enough pieces of "text" in your program. Surely this could have been achieved by changing the approach to handling atoms in the system. I don't see how the current situation is damaging: at the very least, it offers a playground for trying out different handling of "text" in large-scale programs, and surely there will be useful lessons to be learned.

Comment: The situation is damaging because double-quotes are used as their "canonical" representation. Its also damaging because a whole set of new (and effectively untested) set of built-ins is now here reducing stability.   Originally SWI did have a relatively poor atom-management that blocked threads a lot. This is no longer the case.